# How can I receive data that was sent by express on functional component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

```
function Header(props) {  
  const [ serverData, setServerData ] = useState({});

  fetch('http://localhost:4001/api')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setServerData(data);
        console.log(data);
      });

  return (
      <div>{serverData}</div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to make this functional React component to get data from express api.

My code editor keep shutting down, I think that receiving data part is in the loop.

How can I make this functional component to fetch the data just once, without using componentdidmount or class type component.

I tried useCallback, it did not work for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use useEffect hook if you want to do this. If will happen once unless the dependencies change (no dependencies listed here).

```
function Header(props) {  
  const [ serverData, setServerData ] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4001/api')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setServerData(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>{serverData}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Peppermintc i suggest separating the fetch call into another function first and call it inside the `useEffect` hook, as it makes it much more readable and reusable. Eventhough in this current context is fine but in future if you need to add more fetch calls, it will be hard to read and understand. Just a bit worried for code in future if you put all fetch calls inside the useEffect this way

Comment: what a nice comment. I'll keep that in mind for better maintenance

Comment: I agreed. Just to answer his question but this I usually put in services/ folder