# Variable inside UseEffect on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show the variable from API in `variax`

I use axios to access api for django rest-framework and then

put this in variax

But it still shows `2`

I am famillier with `Django` but not `django`

Please give me some help.

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {


  let variax = 1;
  variax = 2;
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/results/')
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res.data);
      variax = res.data;
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
  }, []);
  return(
    <Fragment>
      {variax}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: In react rerenders doesn't happen magically when variable used in the view changes. You have to tell React that something relevant changed manually with `useState`.

Comment: use `state` instead of a variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I receive data that was sent by express on functional component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945129/how-can-i-receive-data-that-was-sent-by-express-on-functional-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are assigning variax in the render body of the component, it will always have the value `2`. I suggest you store the value of variax in the state instead of declare a variable. Try this:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
  const [variax, setVariax] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/results/')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setVariax(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {variax}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: THank you I use `useState()`

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-ssj1d
try using useState hook for variax, in success callback set variax state
let [variax, setVariax] = useState(2)